# Mathematical notation in heteroscedastic mixed models

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to understand how the equations (respecting indices) and the variance and covariance matrices of some mixed models adjusted in R are expressed, which are initially expressed by the `lme4` and `nlme` packages.

The first model is a model of just one random effect on the intercept, this one doesn't seem difficult to me.
Adjusted for example as follows in `lme4` and `nlme` respectively:

```
# Var6 it's a qualitative variable.
# Var7 it's a qualitative variable.
modA_lmer <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(1|Var6), data)
modA_lme <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5),
                           random = ~1|Var6, data)

modB_lmer <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(1|Var7), data)
modB_lme <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5),
                           random = ~1|Var7, data)

modC_lmer <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(1|Var6)+(1|Var7), data)
modC_lme <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5),
                           random= list(Var8= pdIdent(form = ~ 0 + as.factor(Var6)), 
                           Var7 = ~1), data)
```

**I'm not sure** (would it be possible for someone to check? Mainly indexes.), but I think that the equation of the three models, respecting the indices, would be given by:

[image]

I believe that the variance and covariance matrices **D** of the random effects would be expressed by

[image]

Ok, assuming that everything described above is correct, now imagine the mixed model B in a **heterocedastic case**, assuming **different variances** per level of a **dummy variable** `Var 8`, which adjusted through the `lme4` and `nlme` packages would look like:

```
# Var 8 it's a dummy variable
modD_lmer <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(Var8-1||Var6), data)
modD_lme <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5),
                           random = list(Var6=pdDiag(~Var8)), data)
```

In this case, what would the equation of my model look like? I thought of the following situation:

[image]

Is this correct? The equation would be exactly the same but the difference would be the introduction of an index in the sigma^2 of the error?

The other question is, well, in this case, how would the matrix of variances and covariances look like? Would I have three sigmas in the diagonal matrix?
I.e:

[image]

I found some information in :

- https://rpubs.com/bbolker/factorvar
- https://rpubs.com/samuelkn/CovarianceStructuresInR
- [Mathematical notation (or formula) of mixed effect models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435040/mathematical-notation-or-formula-of-mixed-effect-models)

Comment: Hello! I was supposed to have made this post on my account here (without realizing it, I ended up doing it in a way to not be registered). How can I resolve? I already sent a message to support to transfer this post to my main account here.

Comment: @user55546,  You can ask to *merge* accounts. Don't know if both accounts need to be registered.

Comment: I did it, it worked!!!

Comment: Wow, you threw all your rep from the merge into a bounty - it's a very useful question :-) Hope you get some kind of reference answer that is useful for future cases, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here.

#### Models A,B,C

Models A,B,C are fine in both R-Code and formula, however i have some notes.

1. `Var6` and `Var7` are crossed random effects, i.e. their groupings are different/ not nested (also see here: [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228800/341520)), which means that it is not sensible to speak about their covariance matrix, because they don't "realize" on the same objects.
2. `lme` does not inherently support crossed random effects, but you seem to have used the approach from here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/552180/341520 for `modC_lme`, which relies on the `Var8` being a second intercept column, i.e. all 1s.
3. If $k$ is the index of the individual observation, then  $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is redundant, but not wrong. You might be interested in the `equatiomatic` package which can create a Latex-formula from most `lmer`-objects. See the demonstration below.

```r
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(equatiomatic)
n <- 700
# only two fixed effects to reduce redundancy
x1 <- rexp(n)
x2 <- runif(n)
var6 <- sample(as.factor(1:40), replace = T, size = n)
ran_eff6 <- rnorm(40, sd = 1.5)
var7 <- sample(as.factor(1:50), replace = T, size = n)
ran_eff7 <- rnorm(50, sd = 2.5)
# dummy for model D, not the right on for modC_lme!
var8 <- sample(as.factor(1:2), replace = T, size = n)
# model C being true
yC <- exp(3*log(x1) + 2*x2 + ran_eff6[as.integer(var6)] + ran_eff7[as.integer(var7)] + rnorm(n, sd = 4))
dat <- data.frame(x1, x2, var6, var7, var8, yC)

modC_lmer <- lmer(log(yC)~log(x1)+(x2)+(1|var6)+(1|var7), data = dat)

extract_eq(modC_lmer)
```

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{yC}_{i}  &\sim N \left(\alpha_{j[i],k[i]} + \beta_{1}(\operatorname{\log(x1)}) + \beta_{2}(\operatorname{x2}), \sigma^2 \right) \\
    \alpha_{j}  &\sim N \left(\mu_{\alpha_{j}}, \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}} \right)
    \text{, for var7 j = 1,} \dots \text{,J} \\
    \alpha_{k}  &\sim N \left(\mu_{\alpha_{k}}, \sigma^2_{\alpha_{k}} \right)
    \text{, for var6 k = 1,} \dots \text{,K}
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Model D

Here you seem to have gotten confused reading https://rpubs.com/bbolker/factorvar, because your formula describes the simple case of varying variance in $\epsilon_{ijk}$, while your R-Code tries to solve the difficult case of varying variance in $u_i$. Both are correct, they just don't fit together.

Adjusting the formula to the hard case I'd propose writing $u_{i,l}\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_{1, l}),\epsilon_{i,l,k}\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_3) $, while if your formula is correct we can use weights argument in `lme` just as Ben Bolker did in your source:

```r
# generate y with simple heteroscedacity 
dat$yD <- exp(3*log(x1) + 2*x2 + ran_eff6[as.integer(var6)] + rnorm(n, sd = ifelse(var8 == "1", 3, 6)))  
modD_lme <- lme(log(yD)~log(x1)+(x2), random = ~1|var6, weights = varIdent(form=~1|var8), data = dat)
summary(modD_lme)
```

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: dat 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  4021.07 4048.351 -2004.535

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | var6
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.287001 5.716438

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | var8 
 Parameter estimates:
        2         1 
1.0000000 0.5062947 
...more stuff...
```

In `rnorm(n, sd = ifelse(var8 == "1", 3, 6))` we defined $\sigma_{3, 1} = 3$ and  $\sigma_{3, 2} = 6$, which correspond to the residual variance of $\hat\sigma_{3, 2} = 5.716438$ and the parameters under `Variance function` show that this for group $l = 2$ while group $l = 1$ has roughly half that standard deviation. So it fits great! `lme4` has no comparable functionality see here: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#spatial-and-temporal-correlation-models-heteroscedasticity-r-side-models
Ben Bolkers GLMM-FAQ is frankly always worth reading, when dealing with mixed models.

A covariance matrix for the random effects is still not sensible.

Comment: Hi Lukas! I didn't understand some topics. In the case of model D, how many variance components would I have? Do you mean that my model D is not possible to express mathematically by writing the matrix of variance and covariance? If possible, what would it look like? The matrix? Would it or wouldn't it be the matrix D that I wrote?